# R help using a loop add the same column to multiple data frames then fill it with a name defined in a sting

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

Im am trying to add the same column to multiple data frames then fill the column with a name defined in a sting

I hope you can help me, i have been looking at the help but the solutions to similar problems seem a bit too complex for my standard or R use

This is the simplified example of what i'm trying to do;
I have 3 data frames;
East, West and South
In each i want to add a column called "Location"
individually i can do it like this;

```
East["Location"]<-NA
```

then add the name of the data frame as the Location e.g."East"
so i would do it like this
    East$Location<-"East"

Im trying to get it in a loop but as im not very experienced with R i am struggling

I need something like;

```
names<-c("East","West","South")
for (i in 1:3)
{
names[i]["Location"]<-NA
Names[i]$Location<-paste(names[i], sep="")
}
```

I know that this wont work so I need some help working out how I use the list in the string for different purposes

Any help would be much appreciated,
Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much, yes this does what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
names <- c("East","West","South")
modify <- function(dataset) assign(dataset, {df <- get(dataset); df[, "Location"] <- NA; df}, envir = globalenv())
lapply(names, modify)
```

From the "data immutability" point of view, this solution makes me sick to my stomach. But I hate extra typing, so I would 100% come up with something like this.

**Explanation**: `get` retrieves an object from environment by its name, `assign` sets object value by its name with an optional environment argument (we use `globalenv()` to leak the objects outside of modify)

Comment: I think `for (i in seq_along(names)) assign(i, \`[<-\`(get(i),"Location",NA))` works too and dodges environmental entanglements. Anyway, I don't believe you would "100% come up with something like this". `assign` is pretty awful and experienced R users avoid it, by hook or by crook.

Comment: Thank you Anton, this almost does what i want it to although under Location i get NA, so i need to tell it to change NA to the data frame name. the code looks like it should do this so i'm not sure why i get NA.

Comment: It appears I have misread the question. @G.Davies if you use my code, replace `df[, "Location"] <- NA` with `df[, "Location"] <- dataset`.

Comment: Dear @Anton thank you, yes this works I understand now

Answer (score 0):

Generally, having a bunch of data.frames out in the wild is a bad idea.

```
East  = data.frame(a=1:2, b="argh")
North = data.frame(a=2:3, b="ghar")
South = data.frame(a=3:4, b="aghr")
```

First, you can first put them together in a list:

```
DFnames = c("East", "North", "South")
DFlist  = mget(DFnames)

$East
  a    b
1 1 argh
2 2 argh

$North
  a    b
1 2 ghar
2 3 ghar

$South
  a    b
1 3 aghr
2 4 aghr
```

Next, if all of their colnames are the same, as in my example, then you can/should combine them:

```
library(data.table)
DT = rbindlist(DFlist, idcol="Location")

   Location a    b
1:     East 1 argh
2:     East 2 argh
3:    North 2 ghar
4:    North 3 ghar
5:    South 3 aghr
6:    South 4 aghr
```

If they have different colnames, you can do

```
Map(`[<-.data.frame`, DFlist, "Location", value = DFnames)

$East
  a    b Location
1 1 argh     East
2 2 argh     East

$North
  a    b Location
1 2 ghar    North
2 3 ghar    North

$South
  a    b Location
1 3 aghr    South
2 4 aghr    South
```

Comment: Thank you Frank, yes this is what i was trying to do.